# jQuery.get - can the reply be too large?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.get("/url2?key=abc", function(data){eval(data);});
```

This working fine except when the amount of data has grown.

Is there a maximum size you can get data by this method if so how do you get large replies?

Comment: What's the size of the data when it's grown too large? Have you tried visiting the URL and ensuring the data is not being truncated?

Comment: What are you `eval()`ing? JavaScript code or a JSON string?

Comment: I don't believe there is a documented reponse size limit property to the XMLHTTPRequest that is used for the ajax get operation. Actually this should not be a constraint on ajax because the latter is only a technique. I think it is up to the web server to set the limit of the request and response size.

If you're downloading large chunkcs of data, can you do multiple requests? paging if the data is in record form?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is 102330 bytes I think, so about 8 MB's or about 1076ish KB's

Comment: Um... yes they do, I just rounded

Comment: Umm... No they don't... I'm pretty sure you need to check your maths (A LOT)... 102330 bytes = 99KB, 8MB = 8192KB = 8,388,608 bytes and lastly 1076KB = 1,101,824 bytes. There must have been a lot of rounding going on there. Here a site to get you started http://webdeveloper.earthweb.com/repository/javascripts/2001/04/41291/byteconverter.htm

Comment: HAha oops I was looking at Bits instead of Bytes... 0.o Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is any limit on size, but practical considerations come into play:

1) The request can take too long to return, if the server is processing large amounts of data and needs to send it over the wire.

2)  Once the response is returned, it takes too long to do client side calculations.

3)  You return so much data that it increases browser's memory usage too much.

There are no hard and fast rules; if the users can wait a couple minutes to load the app, and have computers with lots of ram, then maybe its ok.  You could also cache via localstorage (assuming you don't need to support older browsers) large data, so you only have to retrieve it once (if it doesn't change, or it doesn't change often).

Note that jsonp is *much* faster at loading and processing large data sets.  So you might want to switch over to it for large datasets.